# Fridgidaire Gallery Powers off for several hours and sometimes days

Tags: repair, refrigerator

I have a Fridgidaire Gallery Model: FGHN2866PF0.

The issue I have is that the fridge powers off for hours at a time and sometimes days at a time. No cooling, no lights in fridge. Only the door control panel stays alive.

The inner door control panel stays lit with the codes OF OF on the Fridge  and freezer temperature readings.

I've changed the main board 3 times. and the control panel as well.
Each time the problem returns after 1 month.

I don't know what else may be causing the issue. It's not the home breaker popping, because the display stay lit.

When the fridge comes back to life, the high temperature alarms go off, the ice maker begins to make ice, the compressor comes on, the lights come on.

What could be wrong?

Comment: It's a long story but if you can trust me; professionally replace all the receptacles in the kitchen including the one the frig is plugged in to.

Comment: Hi,recepticles were replaced as well. Brand new kitchen. I do have power going to the fridge, and the door displays are powered on, the voltage if fine coming in to the fridge, but the fridge remains powerless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally solved the issue.
There was a pinch ground wire from the power cord. The ground was pinched between the frame and housing.
I also found 2 ground wires that were grounded to the compressor. These wires were screwed to the compressor mounting frame, but there was a piece of green tape between the metal and the eye loops of the grounds. Basically, the grounds were not grounded.

Since un-pinching the power line ground wire and removing the tape to allow the other 2 grounds to have a good ground, fridge is working non-stop for 30 days now.
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Here is what I see.  By all appearances you are either loosing the power leg or neutral leg intermittently to the frig. The control panel remains lit because of internal battery function.  When power is restored, the frig starts and is going again.  The vast majority of the time this type of problem is caused by a bad wiring connection in a kitchen receptacle, possible the one the frig is plugged in to.  Unplug the frig from its own receptacle. Use a good quality extension cord and power the frig from a bath room or clothes washer receptacle.(no other receptacle choices & cord no longer than necessary) Monitor its operation here for several days.  This will tell us if we have failure in the frig or in the house wiring. Although very unlikely, you could have a bad breaker.  We will try that next. Also, just because the kitchen and its wiring is new doesn't mean you don't have a problem in one of these receptacles. Are you resetting any GFI receptacles during this process?  Are you resetting breakers during this process.  Are the kitchen circuits on ark-fault breakers? (Do the breakers controlling kitchen circuits have push-buttons on them?)

Comment: I'll try the ext cord now. here's a bit more background info. the fridge is wired on its own breaker no other outlets are running to the same breaker.. Also, I recently replaced my breaker box and all new breakers. Full upgrade because I got a spa in march  and underground pool installed in June.  Yes, I do throw the breaker off and on while technicians where here to repair the fridge. They concluded, very quickly, that the fridge may have a bad wiring. Though when I changed the main board prior to their visit, it would work perfectly for 1 month, then died.

Comment: Ok, I plugged it in using an ext. cord. Fridge makes a beep noise.Fridge also makes a pumping noise for about 8 seconds. kind of like a na na na na na na na noise then stops. No lights. no alarms for high temp. Same result. seems dead. I tried 3 other receptacles in home on different breakers. same results.

Comment: and no, they are not GFI receptacles. but standard home receptacles. Breakers in main home panel.

Comment: One more small thing; if, when you were getting ready to use the cord to power the frig from another source, the frig was running when you unplugged it, you have to leave it off for a least 5-minutes to allow the pressures to equalize before you try to restart it.  Now that that is out of the way.  If this frig is on a dedicated circuit, this changes things a bit.  If you are certain the wiring is good at the receptacle and the breaker is good, then the problem is not in the wiring.  the problem is in the frig.  I'm surprised the service man didn't dig a little deeper.  Sorry no help here.

Comment: Thx Paul. Yes the service man just said, call electrolux head office and try to see if they can replace fridge since its only 18 months old. I called, they said there's nothing they can do since I'm only covered 12 months. I called Visa, who doubles manufacture warranty, and they said, they will reimburse me totality of purchase. So at least I am getting a new fridge now. Sad to see a new fridge die this way though.

Comment: Hey Paul, I ended up, out of curiosity, looking into the wiring of the fridge.I found thet the ground wire from the fridge plug, was pinched when they attached the fridge outer shell to the frame. I released the wire from the pinch.

Comment: I then continued to look, and found 2 ground wires that were screwed to the chasy of the compressor, but had green tape between the wire ring and body, which would not make the 2 grounds groundable. so I unscrewed them and removed the tape, then tighten them back to make a good contact. I then replugged the fridge. The fridge cam on after 2 minutes. then went on and off about 50 times. Each on off was about 30 second cycle. then the fridge stayed off for a few hours, and back on. Now my control panel on fridge door is back alive. I can press buttons and it responds. I'll keep monitoring it.

Answer (score 0):

A good electrician or appliance service tech should be able to trouble shoot this problem.  Someplace in the frig there is a connection that is opening up.  It has nothing to do with grounding wires.  The hot lead or the neutral is opening up somewhere intermittently.  One way that may help you find it is when the unit is in failed condition leave it plugged and start moving things around in there.  Touch and wiggle every place where you see wires coming together.  Get  a good light and look for signs of burning, sparking or heat discoloration.  Look for melted plastic.  Follow the wiring path, pushing and prodding as you go.  A loose connection will show itself with this treatment.  If you get some response, you know you have found the problem.